# Unclear relationship between pointer dereferencing and casting in a specific scenario

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, winapi

I have the following Cpp funtion:

```
u_long stringIpV4ToBinary(const char * ipv4)
{
    u_long * buff[1];
    int ret = InetPton(AF_INET, ipv4, &buff);
    if (ret == -1) return 1;
    if (ret == 0) return 1; // more handling needs to be added

// return ntohl(*buff[0]);           // crash, no warning
// return ntohl((*buff)[0]);         // same meaning above (??) crash, no warning
// return ntohl(**buff);             // crash, no warning
// return ntohl(*(buff[0]));         // crash, no warning
// return ntohl(*(u_long*)buff[0]);  // crash, no warning
// return ntohl((u_long)buff[0]);    // works, but produces warnings:: 'type cast': truncation from 'u_long *' to 'u_long'
// return ntohl(*(u_long*)&buff);    // works
// return ntohl(*(u_long*)&buff[0]); // works
// return ntohl(*(u_long*)buff[0]);  // crash, no warning
// return ntohl(*(u_long*)buff);     // works
}
```

I have spent some time trying to extract the value of buff that I need to pass to `ntohl()` (so you can ignore the first couple of lines). I was playing around with `*buff[0]` `*buff` and others, w/o realizing that I need to cast the value of the first element of the array (`&buff[0]`, `buff` or `&buff`).

**Question**: why do I need to cast the retrieved value to `(u_long*)` and then deference the pointer? Is it ambiguous or unclear to @ runtime that the value held in the `buff[0]` will be a of type `u_long *` ?  My expectation was that `ntohl(**buff)` - (buff is the array name, that decays into a pointer and since the array is of u_long pointers itself) double dereferencing should suffice.

Comment: `InetPton` seems to be a Windows-specific function, so probably worth adding a corresponding tag to this question :)

Comment: @tkausl Sorry, I did not get why is it a char pointer? I believe that is where my misunderstanding lies.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong variable, sorry. Why is it an array of size 1 though? Just use a local `u_long` and take the pointer to that variable.

Comment: InetPton() returns a `binary numeric IP address in network byte order.` and 4 bytes (32 bits) - which is the size of u_long on windows is enough for an IPV4 address.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just declare `buff` as the correct type (an `IN_ADDR`)?

Comment: Yes, you guys are right - better set of data types and usage of `u_long buff;` instead of `u_long * buff[1];` - however, please treat it as me asking why does it need the casting in my specific case. I definitely agree on all the points raised, but why casting is needed in my code example is I think were my knowledge of c/cpp could be expanded :)

Comment: better use [`RtlIpv4StringToAddressEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814459(v=vs.85).aspx) for this task. and despite documentation : Minimum supported client - vista - really on xp this api also exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `buff` defined as an array (of size 1) of *pointer* to `u_long`.  So `InetPton` is storing the resulting IP address directly in this pointer variable.  You then get a crash because this IP address is interpreted as a memory address and dereferenced.

`buff` should be defined as a simple `u_long`, with it's address passed to `InetPton`:

```
u_long buff;
int ret = InetPton(AF_INET, ipv4, &buff);
```

Then you can do this:

```
return ntohl(buff);
```

Improving on this, the MSDN page says the following if the value of the first parameter is `AF_INET`:

> ```
> INT WSAAPI InetPton(
>   _In_  INT     Family,
>   _In_  PCTSTR pszAddrString,
>   _Out_ PVOID  pAddrBuf
> );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> When this parameter is specified, the `pszAddrString` parameter must
>   point to a text representation of an IPv4 address and the `pAddrBuf`
>   parameter returns a pointer to an `IN_ADDR` structure that represents
>   the IPv4 address.

So you should instead be passing in the address of an `IN_ADDR` for the third parameter:

```
IN_ADDR addr;
int ret = InetPton(AF_INET, ipv4, &addr);
...
return ntohl(addr.S_addr);
```

EDIT:

Expanding on why the cast makes a difference, it turns out it doesn't.  What makes a difference is the level of indirection and how many times you dereference.

Comment: `storing the resulting IP address directly in this pointer variable.` - let me try formulate how I understand what you sai. I hope you can correct me in case I'm missing something. I'm passing `&buff` which is equivalent to `&buff[0]` or simply `buff` to `InetPton()`. It pushes the value as the first element of the array. The out parameter for the function is defined as `_Out_ PVOID  pAddrBuf` therefore I should be able to `use u_long * a []` w/o problem. The function `ntohl()` then accepts u_long - which should be obtained from **buff - first `*` defers array, second `*` - get the value?

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius The problem is that the IP address is being stored in `buff[0]` which is of type `u_long *`.  So for example if you passed "127.0.0.1" to `InetPtoN`, then `buff[0]` would (assuming your system is little endian) contain the value 0x0100007f as type `u_long *`.  So `buff[0]` contains the value you want but it's the wrong type.  That's why `(u_long)buff[0]` gets you the expected value.  It's also why `*buff[0]` segfaults, because it means "get the value at address 0x0100007f" which is not a valid address.

Comment: OK, great. Think I understand it now. PVOID is not the `InetPtoN()`'s return type (not sure why I though that it was, since return value is specified at the beginning of the function signature), it is the type of value that it expects - a pointer which in my case is being retrieved with the address-of operator (&) of `buff`. And since `buff[0]` is `u_long *` IP gets stored there and dereferencing it I would get a segfault. The strange mistake I made was thinking that PVOID is somehow a return type - maybe I made this mistake due to programming in C# recently :D Who knows.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter passed to `ntohl` should not need casting.

When parsing a IPv4 string address `InetPton` just needs an address in memory where it can write 4 bytes.

```
u_long addr; // 4 bytes on Windows
int ret = InetPton(AF_INET, ipv4, &addr);
if (ret == -1) return 1;
if (ret == 0) return 1; // more handling needs to be added

return ntohl(addr);
```

Ideally you would use the `IN_ADDR` type instead but if you only care about Windows you can use the `long` based types directly.

Declaring a variable on the stack as a pointer (`*`) to something makes no sense when you need to store data in said variable, this is C 101.

Comment: This was an example I was building upon found on the internet, but  appreciate that it's somehow C 101. Pointers should not be used I agree, just wanted to understand why I see the behavior I see.

Comment: buff is not a storage location. You cannot ask how to retrieve a value in buff[0] because it does not exist. Your buff variable points to a undefined location and when passed to InetPton as a location to write to it could in theory overwrite your master boot record.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `InetPton` writes a 32 bit IPv4 address to the first `u_long *` in `buff`.

All your variants that double-dereference are treating that value as if it were a pointer. It isn't, which is why they crash.

The ones that work manage to do only a single dereference and have the result treated as a long, which is why they work. (Although I suspect many of them actually have unspecified or undefined behaviour since you are being pretty cavalier about whether the value is a pointer or integer.)

If you declared `buff` as an `IN_ADDR` your code could be both simpler and clearly correct.

Comment: I agree with the last point and I will not leave the code as presented in the question. Thanks for helping me out, I appreciate it. So you are saying that `buff` is not a pointer (array) to a `u_long *` pointers? The out param is `_Out_ PVOID  pAddrBuf` for `InetPton()` PVOID, I take is void * - a general purpose pointer so I should be able to use u_long * ? ... seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: As you declared it `buff` is indeed an array of pointers. But the reason the function takes a pointer is to tell it where to write the result; the result is not itself a pointer. You just have to pass the address of a variable of suitable type - see for example @Anders answer. (Note that `_Out_` is not standard C++; here it's essentially a comment.)

Comment: Precisely identified, that were I was mistaken - I though the out keyword specified the return type. Glad I clarified this in my head. Thanks a lot for the help, you made it easier for me to understand the problem :)